# integer overflow in C# with left shift

Tags: c#

I have the following line of code in C#:

```
ulong res = (1<<(1<<n))-1;
```

for some integer n.

As long as n is lower than 5, I get the correct answer.
However, for n>=5, it does not work.

Any idea, using bitwise operators, how to get the correct answer even for n=5 and n=6?
For n=6, the result should be ~0UL, and for n=5, the result should be 0xFFFFFFFF.

Comment: Define "it does not work" please

Comment: (Note that your code doesn't even compile, by the way - there's no implicit conversion from `int` to `ulong`.)

Comment: Indeed, my final version was `(1UL(<<1<<n))-1`, which actually works for n=5 but not for n=6. Jon Skeet gave the explanation I was looking for.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> As long as n is lower than 5, I get the correct answer. However, for n>=5, it does not work.

Well, it obeys the specification. From section 7.9 of the C# 5 spec:

> The << operator shifts x left by a number of bits computed as described below.
>
> For the predefined operators, the number of bits to shift is computed as follows:
>
> - When the type of `x` is `int` or `uint`, the shift count is given by the low-order five bits of `count`. In other words, the shift count is computed from `count & 0x1F`.

So when `n` is 5, `1 << n` (the inner shift) is 32. So you've then got effectively:

```
int x = 32;
ulong res = (1 << x) - 1;
```

Now `32 & 0x1f` is 0... hence you have `(1 << 0) - 1` which is 0.

Now if you make the first operand of the "outer" shift operator `1UL` as suggested by p.s.w.g, you then run into this part of the specification instead:

> - When the type of `x` is `long` or `ulong`, the shift count is given by the low-order six bits of `count`. In other words, the shift count is computed from `count & 0x3F`.

So the code will do as it seems you expect, at least for n = 5 - but not for n = 6.

Comment: Thanks. This is the explanation I was looking for. So for n=6, I must explicitly return ~0UL instead of relying on computations with <<.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the problem is that the constant `1` is considered an `System.Int32` so it assumes that's the datatype you want to operate on, but it quickly overflows the bounds of that datatype. If you change it to:

```
ulong res = (1ul<<(1<<n))-1;
```

It works for me:

```
var ns = new[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
var output = ns.Select(n => (1ul<<(1<<n))-1); 
// { 0x1ul, 0x3ul, 0xful, 0xfful, 0xfffful, 0xfffffffful, 0ul }
```

Comment: Thank you. It works for n=5 but not for n=6 as I want ~0ul instead of 0ul.

Comment: @user1448926 I don't think you can do that with this method, because you will always reach an overflow before subtract 1 from the value. You'd have to use *Strilanc*'s `Bigint` or array method, or perhaps try starting with `~0ul` and right-shifting.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the literal '1' is a 32-bit signed integer, not a 64-bit unsigned long. You're exceeding the range of a 32-bit integer when n is 5 or more.

Changing the appropriate 1 to 1UL fixes the issue, and works for n=5 (but not n=6, which exceeds the range of a ulong).

```
ulong res = (1UL<<(1<<n))-1;
```

Getting it to work for n=6 (i.e. to get 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF) is not as easy. One simple solution is to use a BigInteger, which will remove the issue that bit-shifts by 64 aren't defined for 64-bit integers.

```
// (reference and using System.Numerics)
ulong res = (ulong)(BigInteger.One<<(1<<n)-1)
```

However, that won't be particularly fast. Maybe an array of the constants?

```
var arr = new[] {0x1, 0x3, 0xF, 0xFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF};
ulong res = arr[n];
```